# Timeline marker operators are deselected when the redo panel is used

Tags: scripting

I've written the following operator that works as expected, and modifying values in the redo panel works as expected as long as all of the markers are selected. The problem is when a subset of the markers are selected, modifying values in the redo panel causes all of the markers to be deselected, preventing the operator from operating on them on any redos. Reselecting some of the markers and rerunning the operator (which remembers the modified values) works as expected, until the values are further modified in the redo panel and the markers are deselected again. This seems to be a blender bug, but is there a way I can work around it?

````
class MARKER_OT_marker_spacing_names(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Rename the selected markers after the number of frames between them"""
    bl_idname = "marker.marker_spacing_names"
    bl_label = "Rename markers by frames to next"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    usePrefix: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Preserve Prefix", 
        description = "Preserves each marker name before the last delimiter",
        default = True,
    )

    delimiter: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "Delimiter",
        description = "String used to delimit marker names", 
        default = '*',
    )

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR' or context.area.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR' or context.area.type == 'TIMELINE'


    def execute(self, context):        
        markers = context.scene.timeline_markers
        selected_markers = [m for m in markers if m.select]
        selected_markers.sort(key = lambda x: x.frame)
        
        if len(selected_markers) > 1:
            for curr, next in zip(selected_markers, selected_markers[1:]):
                numStr = str(next.frame - curr.frame)
                if self.usePrefix:
                    prefix = curr.name.split(self.delimiter)[:-1]
                    curr.name = self.delimiter.join(prefix + [numStr])
                else:
                    curr.name = numStr
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```
````